# How to put query results into comma-delimited list in a single column

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Table structure:

```
articles (id, content)
article_tags (article_id, tag_id)
tag (id, name)
```

To select all articles by any tag say "TAG1" I am using

```
SELECT a.*
FROM  
    (SELECT at.article_id AS id
     FROM article_tags at
     JOIN tags t ON t.Id = at.tag_id
     WHERE t.name = 'TAG1') a1
JOIN articles a USING (id);
```

Output:

```
COLUMNS of articles after above query since used a.*
----------------
| id | content |  
----------------
```

Objective:

While running above I get all columns of articles filtered by "TAG1".

But since an article may have more than one tags, I want an additional column in returned results.

So my returned columns would be

```
| id | content |  using_tags |
+----+---------+-------------+ 
|  1 | content | TAG1,TAG2   |
```

Comment: This is often asked. How to put query results into comma-delimited list. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065594/comma-delimited-result-set-sql-query

Comment: I need to know with which additional syntax i can get using_tags column. could be comma separated but i am interested in syntax

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by `which additional syntax i can get using_tags column`.

Comment: For above tables that i posted above,Can you post your suggested query code which matches my objective.I am not good with sql syntax.

Comment: As I said, this question was asked many times already on Stackoverflow. There are plenty of syntax examples to be found here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way...

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS using_tags
FROM (...inner query unchanged...) a1
INNER JOIN articles a USING (id)
LEFT JOIN article_tags at2 ON (a.id = at2.article_id)
LEFT JOIN tags t2 ON (t2.Id = at2.tag_id)
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY x
```

Comment: best possible simple answer.Thank you